# Python dictionary lookup gives error with series

Tags: python

I have a dictionary from which I want to fill the NA values of a dataframe column.
The dictionary looks as below:

```
hist_dict = {3:1,16:1,155:'others'}
```

I am using the below code to fill NAs using another column value in the same dataframe for dictionary lookup.

```
ins_clean['MH1'] = ins_clean['MH1'].fillna(hist_dict.get(ins_clean['MH2']))
```

This gives me the below error:
'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

Please suggest on what needs to be corrected

Thanks

Comment: The error means that `ins_clean['MH2']` cannot be a key. Dictionary keys must be hashable. `ins_clean['MH2']`is a column of the dataframe, am I right? So cannot be a key.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need `map`:

```
ins_clean['MH1'] = ins_clean['MH1'].fillna(ins_clean['MH2'].map(hist_dict))
```